# Why InputStream.read() returns -1?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

my android smartphone is tcpclient and chipkit wf32 wifi module is my tcp server.

```
int bytesRead;
InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1){
       byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
     }
```

The above code reads the data from stream and copies to buffer. If no data is coming it will block. But sometimes i am getting -1. Can anyone explains the reason for getting -1? In document it is mentioned "end of stream is reached". But can you explain the meaning of that? thank you.

Comment: Did you consider consulting the documentation? Before you posted?

Comment: Not a big fan of the javadoc,  arent you ?

Comment: i read it. But i cant able to understand the meaning of end of stream. Can you explain it? is this means socket disconnected or any other socket problem?

Comment: Guys i read the document and then only posted. But couldn't understand much from the document..

Answer (score 1):

If you can read the documentation you will see that `-1` signifies the end of stream:
[InputStream.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()%20for%20this)

so it's natural to get `-1`.

Comment: i cant able to understand the meaning of end of stream. Can you explain it? is this means socket disconnected or any other socket problem?

Comment: if no data is available, it should block, isn't it? But why it is returning -1?

Comment: What do you mean `block`? The stream returns `-1` to let you know that it has ended and so you can make the action you think are necessary. Usually just get input a long as the return value is not `-1`. The first example I stepped on using google: `http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/inputstream_read.htm` should explain that

Comment: The inputstream is associated with the Socket. If i am not sending any data, it usually waits or blocks till i send the data. In the documentation it is mentioned that "Blocks until one byte has been read". But sometimes it returning -1. I can understand the file inputstream example. But i cant relate it to socket inputstream. And i am sorry, i am new to java and android.

Answer (score 0):

**[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read())** says:

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is
>   returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available
>   because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is
>   returned. This method blocks until input data is available, the end of
>   the stream is detected, or an exception is thrown. A subclass must
>   provide an implementation of this method.
>
> Returns:
>       the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.